# Questions on CW complex structure

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

REMARK: I had already posted these questions, about one hour ago, but one of the questions was not what I meant.

I am in the beginning of my studies in Algebraic Topology and am studying CW complexes and identification spaces. I have two questions and I don't know how to approach any of them:

1. Give an example of an identification space which **does not** admit a CW structure.
2. Consider the 2-sphere $S^2$ and let $X\subset S^2$ be a finite subset. Let $S^2/X$ be the quotient space given by the relation $xRy\Longleftrightarrow x,y\in X$. Give a CW complex structure on $S^2/X$.

For the first question, which irregularity should I give to my space so that it does not admit the CW structure? For the second question, should I try to find a space homeomorphic to $S^2/X$?

I would appreciate any hint on the questions! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: CW complexes are locally contractible.

Comment: Consider some badly pathological examples that aren't even manifolds for part 1: the line with a doubled origin, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1 has been answered in principle and 2. is quite a nice question!

One way of doing it is to realize $S^2$ as the union of two hemispheres $E^2_+, E^2_-$ with intersection $S^1$. Then give $S^1$ the structure of a polygon with a set $X$ of $n$ vertices. Now each $E^2_+. E^2_-$ can be given a cell structure with $S^1$ as the $1$-skeleton, and one $2$-cell.  So we get a cell structure for $S^2$, with $n$ $0$-cells, $n$ $1$-cells, and two  $2$-cells.

Now you should be able to see what $S^2/X$ looks like, and what is its cell structure.

More exposition on identification and adjunction spaces, and finite cell complexes,  is given in my book [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html).